# Module 'eAccelerator' already loaded php warning

Tags: php, apache, module, warnings, eaccelerator

I'm getting this PHP warning in my error_log and want to get it fixed.  I'm told it is loaded within php.ini which I've verified as well as a bunch of configuration settings for the module.  I'd like to maintain the module configuration in the place where it's loaded so I need to find out how else to remove it from the list.

Unless removing it from php.ini is just fine.

`Module 'eAccelerator' already loaded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you've got the configuration in multiple files.

If your set up is on Debian (or something like Debian) it could be that eAccelerator is loaded in `php.ini` as well as in a secondary file. For instance, on Debian, `php.ini` lives at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (for PHP 5.x and Apache 2.x). But it also parses all the files in `/etc/php5/conf.d/`, which in my case includes files like `gd.ini`, `mysql.ini`, and `suhosin.ini`. I have see misconfigured packages add configuration to the end of `php.ini` as well as in a separate file in `conf.d`. This will give the kind of error you're seeing.

FYI, this scanning is done with a compile-time configure option (specifically, `--with-config-file-scan-dir=`).